# Losing access to functions within a JS class when running a callback

Tags: javascript, class, tvml, tvjs

I'm working on a TVML/TVJS app and have run into an issue when working with classes in Javascript.

My starting application.js file calls a function

```
resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
resourceLoader.getHomeScreen();
```

I have a separate file called ResourceLoader.js with the following:

```
class ResourceLoader {

getHomeScreen() {
    var homeData = BASEURL + "/home.json";
    var homeTemplate = BASEURL + "/home.tvml";

    this.getRemoteJSON(homeData, homeTemplate, this._jsonLoaded);
}

_jsonLoaded(template, jsonString) {
    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    this.getRemoteXMLFile(template, parsedJSON);
}

getRemoteJSON(file, template, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = "text";
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
        callback(template, xhr.responseText);
    }, false);
    xhr.open("GET", file, true);
    xhr.send();
}

getRemoteXMLFile(template, json) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = "xml";
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
        loadRemoteFile(xhr.responseText, json);
    }, false);
    xhr.open("GET", template, true);
    xhr.send();
}

}
```

(BASEURL is a global variable defined in application.js)

Everything works fine in the beginning. getHomeScreen() is called, it manages to call getRemoteJSON() and pass _jsonLoaded() as the callback. getRemoteJSON does the AJAX call and then runs the callback. This is where the issue happens. Once inside _jsonLoaded, "this" becomes undefined, so when I call this.getRemoteXMLFile, I get the error message "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.getRemoteXMLFile')"

Why was "this" working in getHomeScreen() but not in _jsonLoaded()? How can I access my getRemoteXMLFile function from _jsonLoaded()?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

That is because callback is not a function.

A good solution would be to use ES6 Promises.

Here's an example fetching data using AJAX with a Promise

```
getJson(url) {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            this.get(url).then(
                (value) => {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(value));
                },
                function (reason) {
                    console.error(reason);
                    reject(new Error(reason));
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

And how to call it

```
getJson('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(
    (value) => {
        console.log(value);
    },
    function (reason) {
        console.error(reason);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why was "this" working in getHomeScreen() but not in _jsonLoaded()? How can I access my getRemoteXMLFile function from _jsonLoaded()?

It's technically not specific to TVML app but more of a general JS question, so let me answer `this` (no pun intended) in the light of JavaScript.

When you call `getHomeScreen` you call it on the object instance `resourceLoader.getHomeScreen()`, and hence the `this` context is preserved. But when you pass the `_jsonLoaded` function as a callback argument of the function and do `callback(template, xhr.responseText)`, the object context is lost.

The recently introduced JavaScript `class` keyword [might be confusing](https://medium.com/@TK_CodeBear/prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript-and-how-it-is-different-than-classes-7bfe1626ffdb) for someone with pure OOP language backgrounds, as it's not a object-oriented inheritance, but merely a syntactical sugar to the age old prototypal inheritance in JavaScript. So if one happen to belong to the same group, it's advisable to understand the differences and [gotchas](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/how-to-fix-the-es6-class-keyword-2d42bb3f4caf).

Having said that, one straight and simple solution to your immediate problem statement is to `bind` the `this` context whenever you pass around the function as callback.

```
this.getRemoteJSON(homeData, homeTemplate, this._jsonLoaded.bind(this));
```

*Side note: Have you tried [atvjs](https://emadalam.github.io/atvjs) framework for building TVML apps? It lets you build and quickly prototype apps without much noise, abstracting the underlying hassles and complexities of a conventional TVML app.*